# Column sums in matrix array

Tags: matrices

I am trying to get my equation to look like the following:

[image]

I cannot seem to get anywhere close (is there a way to get labels in `\bordermatrix` to go at the bottom?). Here is my code so far (without the dotted line and column totals)

```
\begin{eqnarray} 
P^{\ast}_{t+1} &=& P_{t+1} + D_{t,t+1} - B_{t,t+1} \\ \nonumber
&=&
\left(
\begin{array}{llll}
1110 &  110 &    10 &   10  \\
  45 &  440 &    45 &    0  \\
  70 &   75 &   770 &   70  \\
  35 &   30 &    30 &  330  \\
\end{array}
\right) + 
\left(
\begin{array}{llll}
44.05 &   3.36 &   0.53 &   0.24  \\
 1.79 &  13.44 &   2.37 &   0.00  \\
 2.78 &   2.29 &  40.53 &   1.71  \\
 1.39 &   0.92 &   1.58 &   8.05  \\
\end{array}
\right) - 
\left(
\begin{array}{llll}
80 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
 0 &    25 &     0 &     0 \\
 0 &     0 &    40 &     0 \\
 0 &     0 &     0 &    40 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: `eqnarray` is depreciated, and most folks recommend something from the `amsmath` package- have a look at [eqnarray-vs-align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: The columns don't sum up to the shown total. Apart from that, do you need that the computation is performed automatically? I'll hope not.

Comment: uploaded the wrong image...my apologies.

Comment: Note, I came here but actually searched sth like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145716/underbrace-in-a-matrix) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109054/highlighted-matrix-with-brackets) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102460/underbraces-in-matrix-divided-in-blocks), which I think is related, and maybe useful for other visitors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way of obtained the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{arydshln}% http://ctan.org/pkg/arydshln
\newcommand{\addsum}[1]{%
  \mathstrut\smash{\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{array}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
  P^{\ast}_{t+1} &= P_{t+1} + D_{t,t+1} - B_{t,t+1} \\
    &=
    \left(
      \begin{array}{rrrr}
        1110 &  110 &    10 &   10 \\
          45 &  440 &    45 &    0 \\
          70 &   75 &   770 &   70 \\
          35 &   30 &    30 &  330
      \end{array}
     \right) + 
     \left(
       \begin{array}{rrrr}
         44.05 &   3.36 &   0.53 &   0.24 \\
          1.79 &  13.44 &   2.37 &   0.00 \\
          2.78 &   2.29 &  40.53 &   1.71 \\
          \addsum{1.39\\50.01} & 
          \addsum{0.92\\20.01} & 
          \addsum{1.58\\45.01} & 
          \addsum{8.05\\10.00} \\ \hdashline
       \end{array}
      \right) - 
      \left(
        \begin{array}{rrrr}
          80 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &    25 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &    40 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &     0 &    40
        \end{array}
      \right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I modified the alignment to be `r`ight for the four columns. With some more work, it would be possible to obtain a centred sum.

The totals are added on a per-column basis using `\addsum` where you specify the information contained in the last and "sum" row. The [`arydshln` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/arydshln) provides the dashed rule. Alternatively, using `\hline` within `\addsum` instead of `\hdashline` yields the following output:

[image]

```
%...
 \left(
   \begin{array}{rrrr}
     44.05 &   3.36 &   0.53 &   0.24 \\
      1.79 &  13.44 &   2.37 &   0.00 \\
      2.78 &   2.29 &  40.53 &   1.71 \\
      \addsum{1.39\\\hline 50.01} & 
      \addsum{0.92\\\hline 20.01} & 
      \addsum{1.58\\\hline 45.01} & 
      \addsum{8.05\\\hline 10.00}
   \end{array}
  \right) - 
%...
```

In both instances, `\smash` removes all vertical height/depth of its contents. As such, be careful when adding contents below this expression. Adding a blank row in the form `\\&` would mostly suffice.

Comment: +1 although if you put `\lipsum[1]` immediately before and after this, it seems that the `smash` distorts the vertical spacing at the end of the environment. Presumably this can be fixed with some manual adjustment?

Comment: That's very similar to my solution; however I'd use a `\hline` in the inner arrays, rather than `\hdashline`. I'd also add an empty line ``\\`` after the row of matrices.

Comment: @cmhughes: I thought about that, and forgot to mention it. Will add, thanks.

Comment: @egreg: Neat suggestion; I'll add.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying out Martin Scharrer's interesting work in [`collcell`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/collcell) package and I managed to get the sums of the columns automatically. It's not tuned for the result since other answers are great anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,collcell,tikz}
\def\columnone#1{#1\expandafter\pgfmathparse\expandafter{\cone + #1}\xdef\cone{\pgfmathresult}}
\def\columntwo#1{#1\expandafter\pgfmathparse\expandafter{\ctwo + #1}\xdef\ctwo{\pgfmathresult}}
\def\columnthree#1{#1\expandafter\pgfmathparse\expandafter{\cthree + #1}\xdef\cthree{\pgfmathresult}}
\def\columnfour#1{#1\expandafter\pgfmathparse\expandafter{\cfour + #1}\xdef\cfour{\pgfmathresult}}

\newcolumntype{X}{>{\collectcell\columnone}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\collectcell\columntwo}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\collectcell\columnthree}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\collectcell\columnfour}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
  P^{\ast}_{t+1} &= P_{t+1} + D_{t,t+1} - B_{t,t+1} \\
    &=
    \left(
      \begin{array}{rrrr}
        1110 &  110 &    10 &   10 \\
          45 &  440 &    45 &    0 \\
          70 &   75 &   770 &   70 \\
          35 &   30 &    30 &  330
      \end{array}
     \right) + \left[
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\def\cone{0} \def\ctwo{0} \def\cthree{0} \def\cfour{0}
\node[inner sep=0] (tabnode) {
\begin{tabular}{XYWZ}
44.05 &   3.36 &   0.53 &   0.24  \\
 1.79 &  13.44 &   2.37 &   0.00  \\
 2.78 &   2.29 &  40.53 &   1.71  \\
 1.39 &   0.92 &   1.58 &   8.05  \\
\end{tabular}
};
\useasboundingbox (tabnode.north east) -- (tabnode.south west);
\draw[dashed] (tabnode.south west) -- (tabnode.south east);
\node[anchor=north] (s1) at (tabnode.205) {\cone};
\node[anchor=north] (s2) at (tabnode.237) {\ctwo};
\node[anchor=north] (s3) at (tabnode.307) {\cthree};
\node[anchor=north] (s4) at (tabnode.338) {\cfour};
\end{tikzpicture}
\right]
- 
      \left(
        \begin{array}{rrrr}
          80 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &    25 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &    40 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &     0 &    40
        \end{array}
      \right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Basically there is a number accumulation going on in the respective macro of each column and then we put that number inside a TikZ node. There are a couple of things among many : First, the node placement is not joyful and requires an automated solution by obtaining column widths and aligning them at the decimal point etc. Second, it's best to reset those registers after the command is executed for successive uses. The number formatting is relatively easy but I skipped it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on `TikZ`. Basic hints are:

- change matrix separator to not have problems with the `align` environment;
- fix the `baseline` position and `inner sep` to adapt dimension.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P^{\ast}_{t+1} &= P_{t+1} + D_{t,t+1} - B_{t,t+1} \\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{llll}
1110 &  110 &    10 &   10  \\
  45 &  440 &    45 &    0  \\
  70 &   75 &   770 &   70  \\
  35 &   30 &    30 &  330  \\
\end{array}
\right)+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.1cm]
%\let\&=\pgfmatrixnextcell % <= one choice to change col separator
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=2.5pt, 
 ampersand replacement=\&] % <= to change col separator for align env
{
\node {44.05}; \& \node{3.36};\& \node {0.53}; \& \node{0.24}; \\
\node {1.79}; \& \node{13.44};\& \node {2.37}; \& \node{0.00};  \\
\node {2.78}; \& \node{2.29}; \&\node {40.53}; \& \node{1.71};  \\
\node(a) {1.39}; \& \node(b){0.92};\& \node(c) {1.58}; \& \node(d){8.05};  \\
};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x/\xtext in {a/50.01,b/20.01,c/45.01,d/10.00}{
% line below last row
\draw ($(\x.south)-(0.3,0.1)$) -- ($(\x.south)+(0.3,-0.1)$);
% sums
\node[shift=(\x.south),yshift=-0.45cm](0,0) {\xtext} ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
- 
\left(
\begin{array}{llll}
80 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
 0 &    25 &     0 &     0 \\
 0 &     0 &    40 &     0 \\
 0 &     0 &     0 &    40 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Graphical result:

[image]

> **IMPROVEMENT**

It is also possible change the code of the picture into (with the same final output):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.1cm]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),inner sep=2.5pt,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
44.05 \&   3.36 \&   0.53 \&   0.24  \\
 1.79 \&  13.44 \&   2.37 \&   0.00  \\
 2.78 \&   2.29 \&  40.53 \&   1.71  \\
 1.39 \&   0.92 \&   1.58 \&   8.05  \\
};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \x/\xtext in {m-4-1/50.01,m-4-2/20.01,m-4-3/45.01,m-4-4/10.00}{
% line below last row
\draw ($(\x.south)-(0.3,0.1)$) -- ($(\x.south)+(0.3,-0.1)$);
% sums
\node[shift=(\x.south),yshift=-0.45cm](0,0) {\xtext} ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The option `ampersand replacement=\&` is more convenient to alter the col seperator. Also you don't need to put the `\node` explicitly since they are already `math nodes` :) Then you can access the bottom nodes as `(matrix node name - row # - col #)` in this example `(m-4-1)` would be the lower left node of the matrix `(m)`

Comment: @percusse: I didn't know this option; I'll try it immediately, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` (and `\cmidrule` of `booktabs`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}% for {pNiceMatrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for \cmirdule

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
  P^{\ast}_{t+1} &= P_{t+1} + D_{t,t+1} - B_{t,t+1} \\
    &=
    \left(
      \begin{array}{rrrr}
        1110 &  110 &    10 &   10 \\
          45 &  440 &    45 &    0 \\
          70 &   75 &   770 &   70 \\
          35 &   30 &    30 &  330
      \end{array}
     \right) + 
       \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,last-row,margin]
         44.05 &   3.36 &   0.53 &   0.24 \\
          1.79 &  13.44 &   2.37 &   0.00 \\
          2.78 &   2.29 &  40.53 &   1.71 \\
         1.39 & 0.92 & 1.58 & 8.05 \\
         \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
         \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
         \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
         \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
         50.01 & 20.01 & 45.01 & 10.00 \\
       \end{pNiceMatrix}
      - 
      \left(
        \begin{array}{rrrr}
          80 &     0 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &    25 &     0 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &    40 &     0 \\
           0 &     0 &     0 &    40
        \end{array}
      \right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]