# Underbrace in a matrix

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I want to display the structure of a matrix as shown in the image below:

[image]

Can this be done using `pmatrix` and `\underbrace`?

My attempt at combining `pmatrix` and `\underbrace` results in a compile error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
%1 & \underbrace{1 & \cdots & 1}_{k} \\ % compile error!
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answers in the following questions may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109054/18228, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102460/18228. In general, [`tikzmark`](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/beware-the-tikzmark-my-son/) would be very useful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A combination of `\smash[b]` should work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{
  \underbrace{\begin{matrix}1 & \cdots & 1\end{matrix}}_{#1}
}

\begin{document}
$
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  && 1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  &&&& \ddots \\
  &&&&& 1 & \block{k}
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{T}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to space the dots in the underbraced blocks, then change the definition:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{
  \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{#1}
}

\begin{document}
$
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  && 1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  &&&& \ddots \\
  &&&&& 1 & \block{k}
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{T}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For getting the underbrace only inside the delimiters, it's more complicated, because we don't want that the underbrace is considered when sizing the delimiters, yet we want to consider the vertical space taken by it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\block}[1]{
  \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{#1}
}

\newcommand{\underbracedmatrix}[2]{%
  \left(\;
  \smash[b]{\underbrace{
    \begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}
  }_{#2}}
  \;\right)
  \vphantom{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}_{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
$
\underbracedmatrix{
  1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  && 1 & \smash[b]{\block{k}} \\
  &&&& \ddots \\
  &&&&& 1 & \block{k}
}{T}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I interprete the OP correct, the brace should not include the surrounding Parentheses.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added the version you asked for.

Comment: Nice. I think the OP---not me---asked for it. `:)`

Comment: @egreg You've put a lot in to this answer. Nice work.

Comment: What does the `[b]` option do to `\smash`?

Comment: @DanielKessler It just removes the depth of the box, so that TeX doesn’t think that the box extends below the baseline. In the particular case it’s not really needed, because every row has a 1 that’s not smashed., but it would be needed otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Just another flavor even though @egreg solutions seems to be robust enough:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\newcommand{\sunderb}[2]{
  \mathclap{\underbrace{\makebox[#1]{$\cdots$}}_{#2}}
}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & \sunderb{3.5em}{k} & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\onegroup{1\hskip\arraycolsep\underbrace{1 \hskip\arraycolsep\dots \hskip\arraycolsep 1}_{k}}

\[
\underbrace{
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\onegroup&&&\\
&\onegroup&&\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&\onegroup
\end{array}
\right)
}_{T}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The output of the code does not match the image which you have pasted, in particular it is missing the large underbrace with the T at the bottom.

Comment: @ILiketoCode Oh! It was an earlier version of code. Corrected.