# Underbracing matrix

Tags: matrices

How to make that look OK? Please help!
[image: How to make that look OK?]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide your code as text to make it easier to look for solutions. Also: please specify what 'looks OK' is in this case.

Comment: include the `\left(...\right)` inside the `\underbrace`and remove `$ $` after `\det`

Comment: Screen shots can be hard to read so it is much better to cut and paste your code into the gui (and highlight it using the `{}` button). This way people can read it more easily *and* they can copy and use it when they try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145718/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\underbracedmatrix}[2]{%
  \left(\;
  \smash[b]{\underbrace{
    \begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}
  }_{#2}}
  \;\right)
  \vphantom{\underbrace{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}}_{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\Delta_n=\det
  \underbracedmatrix{
    A & B \\
    B & A & B \\
      & B & \ddots & \ddots \\
      &   & \ddots & \ddots & B \\
      &   &        & B      & A
  }{n\times n}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Now I will try to understand that :) My first time using TeX.