# Fit a table in a single page

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to fit a table in a single page. If it is not possible, it is acceptable to have it in multiple pages.
My latex code is as shown below :

```
{
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Rate 1/2}
\label{parity_bit_accumulators_2}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
54 9318 14392 27561 26909 10219 2534 8597 \\ \hline
55 7263 4635 2530 28130 3033 23830 3651 \\ \hline
56 24731 23583 26036 17299 5750 792 9169 \\ \hline
57 5811 26154 18653 11551 15447 13685 16264 \\ \hline
58 12610 11347 28768 2792 3174 29371 12997 \\ \hline
59 16789 16018 21449 6165 21202 15850 3186 \\ \hline
60 31016 21449 17618 6213 12166 8334 18212 \\ \hline
61 22836 14213 11327 5896 718 11727 9308 \\ \hline
62 2091 24941 29966 23634 9013 15587 5444 \\ \hline
63 22207 3983 16904 28534 21415 27524 25912 \\ \hline
64 25687 4501 22193 14665 14798 16158 5491 \\ \hline
65 4520 17094 23397 4264 22370 16941 21526 \\ \hline
66 10490 6182 32370 9597 30841 25954 2762 \\ \hline
67 22120 22865 29870 15147 13668 14955 19235 \\ \hline
68 6689 18408 18346 9918 25746 5443 20645 \\ \hline
69 29982 12529 13858 4746 30370 10023 24828 \\ \hline
70 1262 28032 29888 13063 24033 21951 7863 \\ \hline
71 6594 29642 31451 14831 9509 9335 31552 \\ \hline
72 1358 6454 16633 20354 24598 624 5265 \\ \hline
73 19529 295 18011 3080 13364 8032 15323 \\ \hline
74 11981 1510 7960 21462 9129 11370 25741 \\ \hline
75 9276 29656 4543 30699 20646 21921 28050 \\ \hline
76 15975 25634 5520 31119 13715 21949 19605 \\ \hline
77 18688 4608 31755 30165 13103 10706 29224 \\ \hline
78 21514 23117 12245 26035 31656 25631 30699 \\ \hline
79 9674 24966 31285 29908 17042 24588 31857 \\ \hline
80 21856 27777 29919 27000 14897 11409 7122 \\ \hline
81 29773 23310 263 4877 28622 20545 22092 \\ \hline
82 15605 5651 21864 3967 14419 22757 15896 \\ \hline
83 30145 1759 10139 29223 26086 10556 5098 \\ \hline
84 18815 16575 2936 24457 26738 6030 505 \\ \hline
85 30326 22298 27562 20131 26390 6247 24791 \\ \hline
86 928 29246 21246 12400 15311 32309 18608 \\ \hline
87 20314 6025 26689 16302 2296 3244 19613 \\ \hline
88 6237 11943 22851 15642 23857 15112 20947 \\ \hline
89 26403 25168 19038 18384 8882 12719 7093 \\ \hline
0 14567 24965 \\ \hline
1 3908 100 \\ \hline
2 10279 240 \\ \hline
3 24102 764 \\ \hline
4 12383 4173 \\ \hline
5 13861 15918  \\ \hline
6 21327 1046 \\ \hline
7 5288 14579 \\ \hline
8 28158 8069 \\ \hline
9 16583 11098 \\ \hline
10 16681 28363 \\ \hline
11 13980 24725 \\ \hline
12 32169 17989 \\ \hline
13 10907 2767 \\ \hline
14 21557 3818 \\ \hline
15 26676 12422 \\ \hline
16 7676 8754 \\ \hline
17 14905 20232 \\ \hline
18 15719 24646 \\ \hline
19 31942 8589 \\ \hline
20 19978 27197 \\ \hline
21 27060 15071 \\ \hline
22 6071 26649 \\ \hline
23 10393 11176 \\ \hline
24 9597 13370 \\ \hline
25 7081 17677 \\ \hline
26 1433 19513 \\ \hline
27 26925 9014 \\ \hline
28 19202 8900 \\ \hline
29 18152 30647 \\ \hline
30 20803 1737 \\ \hline
31 11804 25221 \\ \hline
32 31683 17783 \\ \hline
33 29694 9345 \\ \hline
34 12280 26611 \\ \hline
35 6526 26122 \\ \hline
36 26165 11241 \\ \hline
37 7666 26962 \\ \hline
38 16290 8480 \\ \hline
39 11774 10120 \\ \hline
40 30051 30426 \\ \hline
41 1335 15424 \\ \hline
42 6865 17742 \\ \hline
43 31779 12489 \\ \hline
44 32120 21001 \\ \hline
45 14508 6996 \\ \hline
46 979 25024 \\ \hline
47 4554 21896 \\ \hline
48 7989 21777 \\ \hline
49 4972 20661 \\ \hline
50 6612 2730 \\ \hline
51 12742 4418 \\ \hline
52 29194 595 \\ \hline
53 19267 20113  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
}
```

Comment: How many many numbers are there per row?

Comment: 35 rows with 8 columns
and the rest with 4 columns.
My main concern is to fit it in one page, or in two pages.

Comment: The rest seems to have `3` columns, not 4. Could we have the rest at the right of the rows with 8 columns?

Comment: My bad sorry, the rest have 3 columns. Yes, the rest can be written to the right side.

Comment: Please see the comment of user daleif on your first question here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353155): (Please) provide a complete but minimal code.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have given a complete code now.

Comment: @Mitun_C Do you really have a leading `{` and a trailing `}`? If so, remove them: they are just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See one of these corresponds to what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, table, svgnames]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe, adjustbox}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[]
%\centering\small
%\caption{Rate 1/2}
%\label{parity_bit_accumulators₂}
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
%\hline
%54 9318 14392 27561 26909 10219 2534 8597 & 22 6071 26649 \\ \hline
%55 7263 4635 2530 28130 3033 23830 3651 & 23 10393 11176 \\ \hline
%56 24731 23583 26036 17299 5750 792 9169 & 24 9597 13370 \\ \hline
%57 5811 26154 18653 11551 15447 13685 16264 & 25 7081 17677 \\ \hline
%58 12610 11347 28768 2792 3174 29371 12997 & 26 1433 19513 \\ \hline
%59 16789 16018 21449 6165 21202 15850 3186 & 27 26925 9014 \\ \hline
%60 31016 21449 17618 6213 12166 8334 18212 & 28 19202 8900 \\ \hline
%61 22836 14213 11327 5896 718 11727 9308 & 29 18152 30647 \\ \hline
%62 2091 24941 29966 23634 9013 15587 5444 & 30 20803 1737 \\ \hline
%63 22207 3983 16904 28534 21415 27524 25912 & 31 11804 25221 \\ \hline
%64 25687 4501 22193 14665 14798 16158 5491 & 32 31683 17783 \\ \hline
%65 4520 17094 23397 4264 22370 16941 21526 & 33 29694 9345 \\ \hline
%66 10490 6182 32370 9597 30841 25954 2762 & 34 12280 26611 \\ \hline
%67 22120 22865 29870 15147 13668 14955 19235 & 35 6526 26122 \\ \hline
%68 6689 18408 18346 9918 25746 5443 20645 & 36 26165 11241 \\ \hline
%69 29982 12529 13858 4746 30370 10023 24828 & 37 7666 26962 \\ \hline
%70 1262 28032 29888 13063 24033 21951 7863 & 38 16290 8480 \\ \hline
%71 6594 29642 31451 14831 9509 9335 31552 & 39 11774 10120 \\ \hline
%72 1358 6454 16633 20354 24598 624 5265 & 40 30051 30426 \\ \hline
%73 19529 295 18011 3080 13364 8032 15323 & 41 1335 15424 \\ \hline
%74 11981 1510 7960 21462 9129 11370 25741 & 42 6865 17742 \\ \hline
%75 9276 29656 4543 30699 20646 21921 28050 & 43 31779 12489 \\ \hline
%76 15975 25634 5520 31119 13715 21949 19605 & 44 32120 21001 \\ \hline
%77 18688 4608 31755 30165 13103 10706 29224 & 45 14508 6996 \\ \hline
%78 21514 23117 12245 26035 31656 25631 30699 & 46 979 25024 \\ \hline
%79 9674 24966 31285 29908 17042 24588 31857 & 47 4554 21896 \\ \hline
%80 21856 27777 29919 27000 14897 11409 7122 & 48 7989 21777 \\ \hline
%81 29773 23310 263 4877 28622 20545 22092 & 49 4972 20661 \\ \hline
%82 15605 5651 21864 3967 14419 22757 15896 & 50 6612 2730 \\ \hline
%83 30145 1759 10139 29223 26086 10556 5098 & 51 12742 4418 \\ \hline
%84 18815 16575 2936 24457 26738 6030 505 & 52 29194 595 \\ \hline
%85 30326 22298 27562 20131 26390 6247 24791 & 53 19267 20113 \\ \hline
%86 928 29246 21246 12400 15311 32309 18608 \\ \hline
%87 20314 6025 26689 16302 2296 3244 19613 \\ \hline
%88 6237 11943 22851 15642 23857 15112 20947 \\ \hline
%89 26403 25168 19038 18384 8882 12719 7093 \\ \hline
%0 14567 24965 \\ \hline
%1 3908 100 \\ \hline
%2 10279 240 \\ \hline
%3 24102 764 \\ \hline
%4 12383 4173 \\ \hline
%5 13861 15918 \\ \hline
%6 21327 1046 \\ \hline
%7 5288 14579 \\ \hline
%8 28158 8069 \\ \hline
%9 16583 11098 \\ \hline
%10 16681 28363 \\ \hline
%11 13980 24725 \\ \hline
%12 32169 17989 \\ \hline
%13 10907 2767 \\ \hline
%14 21557 3818 \\ \hline
%15 26676 12422 \\ \hline
%16 7676 8754 \\ \hline
%17 14905 20232 \\ \hline
%18 15719 24646 \\ \hline
%19 31942 8589 \\ \hline
%20 19978 27197 \\ \hline
%21 27060 15071 \\ \hline
%
%\end{tabular}
% \end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\small
  \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3.2pt}
  \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2.7pt}
  \caption{Rate 1/2}
  \label{parity_bit_accumulators₂}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|Sl|}
    \hline
    54 9318 14392 27561 26909 10219 2534 8597 \\ \hline
    55 7263 4635 2530 28130 3033 23830 3651 \\ \hline
    56 24731 23583 26036 17299 5750 792 9169 \\ \hline
    57 5811 26154 18653 11551 15447 13685 16264 \\ \hline
    58 12610 11347 28768 2792 3174 29371 12997 \\ \hline
    59 16789 16018 21449 6165 21202 15850 3186 \\ \hline
    60 31016 21449 17618 6213 12166 8334 18212 \\ \hline
    61 22836 14213 11327 5896 718 11727 9308 \\ \hline
    62 2091 24941 29966 23634 9013 15587 5444 \\ \hline
    63 22207 3983 16904 28534 21415 27524 25912 \\ \hline
    64 25687 4501 22193 14665 14798 16158 5491 \\ \hline
    65 4520 17094 23397 4264 22370 16941 21526 \\ \hline
    66 10490 6182 32370 9597 30841 25954 2762 \\ \hline
    67 22120 22865 29870 15147 13668 14955 19235 \\ \hline
    68 6689 18408 18346 9918 25746 5443 20645 \\ \hline
    69 29982 12529 13858 4746 30370 10023 24828 \\ \hline
    70 1262 28032 29888 13063 24033 21951 7863 \\ \hline
    71 6594 29642 31451 14831 9509 9335 31552 \\ \hline
    72 1358 6454 16633 20354 24598 624 5265 \\ \hline
    73 19529 295 18011 3080 13364 8032 15323 \\ \hline
    74 11981 1510 7960 21462 9129 11370 25741 \\ \hline
    75 9276 29656 4543 30699 20646 21921 28050 \\ \hline
    76 15975 25634 5520 31119 13715 21949 19605 \\ \hline
    77 18688 4608 31755 30165 13103 10706 29224 \\ \hline
    78 21514 23117 12245 26035 31656 25631 30699 \\ \hline
    79 9674 24966 31285 29908 17042 24588 31857 \\ \hline
    80 21856 27777 29919 27000 14897 11409 7122 \\ \hline
    81 29773 23310 263 4877 28622 20545 22092 \\ \hline
    82 15605 5651 21864 3967 14419 22757 15896 \\ \hline
    83 30145 1759 10139 29223 26086 10556 5098 \\ \hline
    84 18815 16575 2936 24457 26738 6030 505 \\ \hline
    85 30326 22298 27562 20131 26390 6247 24791 \\ \hline
    86 928 29246 21246 12400 15311 32309 18608 \\ \hline
    87 20314 6025 26689 16302 2296 3244 19613 \\ \hline
    88 6237 11943 22851 15642 23857 15112 20947 \\ \hline
    89 26403 25168 19038 18384 8882 12719 7093 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}0 14567 24965 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}1 3908 100 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}2 10279 240 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}3 24102 764 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}4 12383 4173 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}5 13861 15918 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}6 21327 1046 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}7 5288 14579 \\ \hline
    \phantom{0}8 28158 8069 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|Sl|}
    \hline
    \phantom{0}9 16583 11098 \\ \hline
    10 16681 28363 \\ \hline
    11 13980 24725 \\ \hline
    12 32169 17989 \\ \hline
    13 10907 2767 \\ \hline
    14 21557 3818 \\ \hline
    15 26676 12422 \\ \hline
    16 7676 8754 \\ \hline
    17 14905 20232 \\ \hline
    18 15719 24646 \\ \hline
    19 31942 8589 \\ \hline
    20 19978 27197 \\ \hline
    21 27060 15071 \\ \hline
    22 6071 26649 \\ \hline
    23 10393 11176 \\ \hline
    24 9597 13370 \\ \hline
    25 7081 17677 \\ \hline
    26 1433 19513 \\ \hline
    27 26925 9014 \\ \hline
    28 19202 8900 \\ \hline
    29 18152 30647 \\ \hline
    30 20803 1737 \\ \hline
    31 11804 25221 \\ \hline
    32 31683 17783 \\ \hline
    33 29694 9345 \\ \hline
    34 12280 26611 \\ \hline
    35 6526 26122 \\ \hline
    36 26165 11241 \\ \hline
    37 7666 26962 \\ \hline
    38 16290 8480 \\ \hline
    39 11774 10120 \\ \hline
    40 30051 30426 \\ \hline
    41 1335 15424 \\ \hline
    42 6865 17742 \\ \hline
    43 31779 12489 \\ \hline
    44 32120 21001 \\ \hline
    45 14508 6996 \\ \hline
    46 979 25024 \\ \hline
    47 4554 21896 \\ \hline
    48 7989 21777 \\ \hline
    49 4972 20661 \\ \hline
    50 6612 2730 \\ \hline
    51 12742 4418 \\ \hline
    52 29194 595 \\ \hline
    53 19267 20113 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{table}[!htb]\centering%
  \setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
  \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3.5pt}
  \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
  \caption{Rate 1/2}
  \label{parity_bit_accumulators₂}
  \rowcolors{1}{Gainsboro!25}{Gainsboro!50!Lavender!}
  \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!60!RoyalBlue}
  \small
  \begin{tabular}[t]{Sl}
    \toprule[0.5ex]
    54 9318 14392 27561 26909 10219 2534 8597 \\
    55 7263 4635 2530 28130 3033 23830 3651 \\
    56 24731 23583 26036 17299 5750 792 9169 \\
    57 5811 26154 18653 11551 15447 13685 16264 \\
    58 12610 11347 28768 2792 3174 29371 12997 \\
    59 16789 16018 21449 6165 21202 15850 3186 \\
    60 31016 21449 17618 6213 12166 8334 18212 \\
    61 22836 14213 11327 5896 718 11727 9308 \\
    62 2091 24941 29966 23634 9013 15587 5444 \\
    63 22207 3983 16904 28534 21415 27524 25912 \\
    64 25687 4501 22193 14665 14798 16158 5491 \\
    65 4520 17094 23397 4264 22370 16941 21526 \\
    66 10490 6182 32370 9597 30841 25954 2762 \\
    67 22120 22865 29870 15147 13668 14955 19235 \\
    68 6689 18408 18346 9918 25746 5443 20645 \\
    69 29982 12529 13858 4746 30370 10023 24828 \\
    70 1262 28032 29888 13063 24033 21951 7863 \\
    71 6594 29642 31451 14831 9509 9335 31552 \\
    72 1358 6454 16633 20354 24598 624 5265 \\
    73 19529 295 18011 3080 13364 8032 15323 \\
    74 11981 1510 7960 21462 9129 11370 25741 \\
    75 9276 29656 4543 30699 20646 21921 28050 \\
    76 15975 25634 5520 31119 13715 21949 19605 \\
    77 18688 4608 31755 30165 13103 10706 29224 \\
    78 21514 23117 12245 26035 31656 25631 30699 \\
    79 9674 24966 31285 29908 17042 24588 31857 \\
    80 21856 27777 29919 27000 14897 11409 7122 \\
    81 29773 23310 263 4877 28622 20545 22092 \\
    82 15605 5651 21864 3967 14419 22757 15896 \\
    83 30145 1759 10139 29223 26086 10556 5098 \\
    84 18815 16575 2936 24457 26738 6030 505 \\
    85 30326 22298 27562 20131 26390 6247 24791 \\
    86 928 29246 21246 12400 15311 32309 18608 \\
    87 20314 6025 26689 16302 2296 3244 19613 \\
    88 6237 11943 22851 15642 23857 15112 20947 \\
    89 26403 25168 19038 18384 8882 12719 7093 \\
    \phantom{0}0 14567 24965 \\
    \phantom{0}1 3908 100 \\
    \phantom{0}2 10279 240 \\
    \phantom{0}3 24102 764 \\
    \phantom{0}4 12383 4173 \\
    \phantom{0}5 13861 15918 \\
    \phantom{0}6 21327 1046 \\
    \phantom{0}7 5288 14579 \\
    \phantom{0}8 28158 8069 \\
    \bottomrule[0.5ex]
  \end{tabular}
  \qquad
  %\rowcolors{1}{Gainsboro!50!Lavender!}{Gainsboro!25}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{Sl}
    \toprule[0.5ex]
    \phantom{0}9 16583 11098 \\
    10 16681 28363 \\
    11 13980 24725 \\
    12 32169 17989 \\
    13 10907 2767 \\
    14 21557 3818 \\
    15 26676 12422 \\
    16 7676 8754 \\
    17 14905 20232 \\
    18 15719 24646 \\
    19 31942 8589 \\
    20 19978 27197 \\
    21 27060 15071 \\
    22 6071 26649 \\
    23 10393 11176 \\
    24 9597 13370 \\
    25 7081 17677 \\
    26 1433 19513 \\
    27 26925 9014 \\
    28 19202 8900 \\
    29 18152 30647 \\
    30 20803 1737 \\
    31 11804 25221 \\
    32 31683 17783 \\
    33 29694 9345 \\
    34 12280 26611 \\
    35 6526 26122 \\
    36 26165 11241 \\
    37 7666 26962 \\
    38 16290 8480 \\
    39 11774 10120 \\
    40 30051 30426 \\
    41 1335 15424 \\
    42 6865 17742 \\
    43 31779 12489 \\
    44 32120 21001 \\
    45 14508 6996 \\
    46 979 25024 \\
    47 4554 21896 \\
    48 7989 21777 \\
    49 4972 20661 \\
    50 6612 2730 \\
    51 12742 4418 \\
    52 29194 595 \\
    53 19267 20113 \\
    \bottomrule[0.5ex]
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This will not suit the purpose. Thanks for the help.
I need to be of this structure : mentioned in page page number 40, of this document :
http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/302300_302399/302307/01.02.01_60/en_302307v010201p.pdf

Comment: @Mitun_C: I've just updated my answer, with two suggestions. Is is more like you want? Thee code is more easily modifiable than the first version.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much for your help. It works like a charm.